what bits in an arm64 instruction is the operation code?
10101001101111100111101111111101
a9be7bfd

this is the binary for
stp x29, x30, [sp, #-32]

I know bit 31-30 is the 64 bit-32 bit bits, bits 0-14 is for the registers, and bits 15, 21 is for the immediate offset, but which bits are the operation code/instruction itself.
I tried googling it, but since I'm looking something up for Arm64 Assembly that's that intimate, of course I didn't get any results, and I tried looking in the arm64 a-profile architecture reference manual, but I couldn't find an explanation for it.

https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0596/2020-12/Base-Instructions/STP--Store-Pair-of-Registers-?lang=en

When you read the link provided by interjay the bits that have specific hardcoded 0 or 1 values are the opcode bits.

Many architectures employ some variable length opcode.  For example, MIPS has 6 bits known as "opcode", but the opcode value 0 is shared by all R-Type instructions (reg reg reg add, subtract, and, or, etc..), and they are then further differentiated by another sub-opcode field called funct.

ARM instruction encoding is fairly complex.  It's not as simple as something like "bits 19-27 are the opcode" across all instructions.  The encoding is explained in chapter C4 of the Architecture Reference Manual in a sort of hierarchical way: some bits (25-28) distinguish between different groups of instructions, and within each group, there are other bits distinguishing between the instructions (or sub-groups) within that group, but not always the same ones.
